# Installing TwitterBootStrap in MVC4 Using VisualStudio 2012

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to install TwitterBootstrap in MVC4 Application using nugget package manager.
Here I followed the procedure.

1. Created An Empty MVC4 Application.
2. Gone to Nugget package manager and installed the package named 
   Twitter Bootstrap for ASP.Net MVC4 Sample.
3. As I Click on install the following packages are installed.
     -->Twitter BootStrap for Asp.net MVC4(BootStrap Layout)
     -->Twitter BootStrap for Asp.net MVC4(HTML Helpers for Project)
     -->BootStrap 3.0.0
4. AS I completed the installation so many files like controllers, views, .css and .js      files are created.
5. When I run the application in any browser the styles are not applying to the views.
   The Output looks as following. [image: No styles are displaying]
   6.What might be the problem? Is there any workaround to overcome this issue?
   7.Kindly provide suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the bootstrap.css path is wrongly configured on "\~App_Start\BootstrapBundleConfig.cs" file. Make the following changes it will work.

```
  "~/Content/bootstrap/bootstrap.css",
```